# how to apply += with pageddatasource

Tags: c#, datasource, paging

I have a for loop and I want to add paged data source using

```
pageddatasource += pageddatasource
```

Here is my code

```
string[] arrSearchFilter = SearchFilter.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < arrSearchFilter.Length; i++)
{
    pData += ctr.GetAllProjectsNoLOCandSt(
                     Convert.ToInt16(arrSearchFilter[i]), this.ModuleId);
}
```

where

```
ctr.GetAllProjectsNoLOCandSt(Convert.ToInt16(arrSearchFilter[i]), this.ModuleId);
```

is a stored procedure return a paged datasource

and

```
pData
```

is Paged Data Source
Could any one help me please ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can't add items to a `PagedDataSource`. You'd have to add the items to whatever the `PagedDataSource` is using as its `DataSource` (assuming that collection allows you to add items).

Answer (score 0):

There is no natural way to combine `PagedDataSource` results, because they are intended to be the final result for binding a display control.  However, since `PagedDataSource` does implement `IEnumerable`, you could manually iterate the results and combine them into some merged collection:

```
List<object> results = new List<object>();

string[] arrSearchFilter = SearchFilter.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < arrSearchFilter.Length; i++)
{
    var pData = ctr.GetAllProjectsNoLOCandSt(
                        Convert.ToInt16(arrSearchFilter[i]), this.ModuleId);
    foreach (var result in pData)
        results.Add(result);
}

// do something with `results` collection
```